# Not able to figure out the logical error in C program

Tags: c, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

A program that prints its input one word per line.

```
int main() {

    int c;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (c== ' ' || c== '\n' ||c == '\t')
                putchar('\n');
        else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program prints the result correctly, one word per line. After changing the condition accordingly, I was expecting the program below to also print one word per line. However I am not getting the correct result. Am I making some silly mistake or is something wrong?

```
int main() {

    int c;

    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t')
            putchar(c);
        else {
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the correct change of condition is:

```
if (!(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'))
```

or

```
if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
```

See [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: @che - thanks. I thought about it but was too lazy to edit for that :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake.It was really silly of me.Still loads to learn....

Answer (score 4):

You've gotten a number of answers to your original question, but I feel obliged to add one minor detail: both the original and the modified version suffer from a couple of what I'd consider problems. First, they don't really detect white-space correctly (e.g., they ignore vertical tabs, and any other white-space as defined by the locale), and they produce blank lines if words are separated by more than one white-space character.

For the first problem, I'd use `isspace` instead of directly comparing to the white-space characters you know about (incidentally, eliminating the source of the problem you encountered). For the second, you could add some logic to skip all consecutive white-space characters when you encounter the first, or you could add a flag to write out a new-line if and only if the current character is a space *and* the previous character you wrote was not a new-line.

Alternatively, you could read words using `scanf` with the `%s` conversion:

```
char buffer[256];

while (scanf("%255s", buffer))
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

This approach, however, imposes an upper limit on the size of a single word. Under normal circumstances, that's rarely problem, but depending on the nature of the input it could/can be.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the problems with programme.I will try it too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `||`s to `&&`s, i.e. change

```
        if (c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t')
```

to

```
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
```

i.e. "IF c not equal to space AND c not equal to return AND c not equal to tab THEN ..."

Answer (score 2):

Remember your logic programming classes:

```
!(A || B) == (!A && !B)
!(A && B) == (!A || !B)
```

In other words: your condition needs to read like this:

```
if ( c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do what MByD said, or you could change your or's (||) to and's (&&).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your conditional expression. When you negate the first expression

```
!(c== ' ' || c== '\n' ||c == '\t')
```

you get:

```
c!= ' ' && c!= '\n' &&c != '\t'
```

and not you defined in your question.

Remember:

(A && B) is the same as (!A || !B)

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `A or B or C` is `not A and not B and not C`, so use:

```
if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to study a bit more on [DeMorgan's Laws](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  It is not enough to change the combination operators from "||" to "&&", you must also negate all of the elements being combined to obtain the same solution set.